# How to get the type of an arbitrary expression in a file in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

`:type` is not enough because the expression I want might include locally defined variables like things assigned with `<-`, `let` or `where`. Typed holes (replacing the expression with `_` and loading with ghc) are close, but they give you what's accepted there, which might be more general than the expression you're curious about.

I thought I found the jackpot with `:type-at`, but I can't get it to work like I'd hope. With this file, named "thing.hs":

```
something :: ()
something = ()

main :: IO ()
main = return something
```

This is the result I get when using `:type-at`:

```
> :set +c
> :l thing.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( thing.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
Collecting type info for 1 module(s) ... 
> :type-at thing.hs 5 8 5 13 -- "return" on last line

<no location info>: error: not an expression: ‘’
> :type-at thing.hs 5 1 5 4 -- "main" on last line
 :: IO ()
> :type-at thing.hs 5 15 5 23 -- "something" on last line

<no location info>: error: not an expression: ‘’
```

That's basically the same as using `:type`. I was hoping I'd even be able to pass it the span for `return something` and get `Monad a => a ()` or `IO ()`. Would be even cooler if one could select between seeing the type of the expression alone and the type of the expression "at that point" (after being restricted by the type that would appear with a type hole), but either would be fine.

Comment: I notice that ghci does not propose :type-at command when typing :t followed by completion. I had to find your post to discover the existence of this feature

Comment: For future reference, here's the link in the docs (it's hard to search for hyphenated terms on the interwebs): https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#ghci-cmd-:type-at. Also: both row- and column are 1-indexed, the start location is inclusive, the end location exclusive.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I try `:type-at thing.hs 5 8 5 14`, I get `:: () -> IO ()`.  `:type-at thing.hs 5 14 5 24` also works, as does `:type-at thing.hs 5 14 6 1`.

So, the right bound should be the cell one past the end of the expression.

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. So it was just an off-by-one error. :P

Comment: Not well-documented.

Comment: It definetely could be better documented. I tried using 0-based indices, but I didn't think about just moving the right bound.

Comment: But thanks for making me aware that exists. I’ve been using typed holes, but might even use it someday.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes one can simply use a typed hole *in front* of the expression you are curious about works, using the hole as if it were a function. For instance

```
return (f 3)
---->
return (_ (f 3))
```

In this way, the hole will be typed with something like `WantedType -> OtherType`, where `WantedType` is the type of `f 3`.

This is not ideal, though, since the hole will prevent type inference to do its job. I.e., sometimes the type of `f 3` is polymorphic, and its context forces it to be instantiated. For instance, `4 + length []` makes `4` to be `Int`, even if it can be of any `Num` type. Using `(_ 4) + length []` introduces a function between the arbitrary `Num` type (which will get defaulted to `Integer`) and the needed `Int`, making type inference misbehave.

Instead, an alternative could be to use the translation

```
return (f 3)
------>
return (f 3 `asTypeOf` _)
```

This should play better with the type inference, and return the right™ type.

Of course, figuring out how `:type-at` works should be better. Still, the type hole trick is not too inconvenient when you have an editor already open at the spot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @chi answer can be improved (by avoiding the type inference issue ) by using a Dummy unary type constructor which does not implement the Show typeclass and using it with the print function :

```
someExpressionWeSearchType = Right $ Just (1 , ["Foo"] , getLine)

data Dummy a = Dummy a


main = do
  putStrLn "Here we go"
  --some code here...
  let exp  = someExpressionWeSearchType
  --Debug stuff => 
  print $ Dummy exp

  -- other code here 
  putStrLn "Done"
```

This gives the following result when loaded :

```
Prelude> :l test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:11:3: error:
    * No instance for (Show
                         (Dummy (Either a0 (Maybe (Bool, [[Char]], IO String)))))
        arising from a use of `print'
    * In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ Dummy exp
      In the expression:
        do putStrLn "Here we go"
           let exp = someExpressionWeSearchType
           print $ Dummy exp
           putStrLn "Done"
      In an equation for `main':
          main
            = do putStrLn "Here we go"
                 let exp = ...
                 print $ Dummy exp
                 ....
   |
11 |   print $ Dummy exp
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

So we can see that type inside the Dummy : **Either a0 (Maybe (Bool, [[Char]], IO String))**